# AngularJS - TypeError: Cannot read property 'canonicalUrl' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ecmascript-6, typeerror

I'm working on an app in AngularJS using ES6, but I'm trying to do it in a way that will fit for AngularJS 2.0, so I'm using "Angular new router"

Application.js:
application is a directive and it is placed in the `<html>` tag as an attribute

```
class Application {

    constructor($router) {
        this.$router = $router;
        this.routing();
    }

    routing(){
        this.$router.config(
            {
                path: '/',
                component: 'main'
                //component: {'main': 'main'} // view-name:component => name.html, NameController
            },
            {
                path: '/doctors',
                component: 'doctors'
            }
        );
    }

}

Application.$inject = ['$router'];

export default function() {
    return {
        scope: {},
        controller: Application,
        controllerAs: 'applicationCtrl'
    };
};
```

Dashboard.js:

```
import doctorsCtrl from "../../page/dashboard/DoctorsCtrl.js"; // controller for the component
import mainCtrl from "../../page/dashboard/MainCtrl.js";
import doctors from "./widget/doctors/Doctors.js";


angular.module('agenda.dashboard', ['ngNewRouter'])

    .directive("application", application)
    .directive("doctors", doctors)

    .config(function ($componentLoaderProvider) {
        $componentLoaderProvider.setTemplateMapping(function (name) {
            return 'page/dashboard/' + dotCase(name) + '.html';
        });

        $componentLoaderProvider.setCtrlNameMapping(function (name) {
            return name[0].toUpperCase() + name.substr(1) + 'Ctrl';
        });
    })

    .controller('MainCtrl', mainCtrl)
    .controller('DoctorsCtrl', doctorsCtrl);


    function dotCase(str) {
    return str.replace(/([A-Z])/g, function ($1) {
        return '.' + $1.toLowerCase();
    });
}
```

Main ('/') works correctly, but when I try to open ('/doctors') I get the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'canonicalUrl' of undefined
>
> ```
> at Grammar.recognize (router.es5.js:1453)
>
> at RootRouter.recognize (router.es5.js:752)
>
> at RootRouter.navigate (router.es5.js:680)
>
> at RootRouter.$$rootRouter.navigate (router.es5.js:94)
>
> at Object.fn (router.es5.js:89)
>
> at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:15556)
>
> at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:15824)
>
> at bootstrapApply (angular.js:1628)
>
> at Object.invoke (angular.js:4426)
>
> at doBootstrap (angular.js:1626)
> ```

Comment: is the doctors variable defined? what do you get if you console.log(doctors)?

Comment: @Braim do you mean this `import doctors from "./widget/doctors/Doctors.js";` ?

Comment: The doctors variable passed to the directive method. Just before the angular.module method, put the console.log line

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that what you pass to `.config()` is supposed to be an array.

so when I change it to this:

```
routing(){
        this.$router.config(
         [ // NOTE THIS
            {
                path: '/',
                component: 'main'
                //component: {'main': 'main'} // view-name:component => name.html, NameController
            },
            {
                path: '/doctors',
                component: 'doctors'
            }
         ] // NOTE THIS

        );
    }
```

It works perfectly.